# How does the {variable} statement in Javascript work?

Tags: javascript

When reading through the documentation for an NPM package, I came across the following code:

```
const {OperationHelper} = require('apac');
```

This object was then used later like so:

```
const opHelper = new OperationHelper({..})
```

I'm unfamiliar with the `{OperationHelper}` assignment - a variable name inside a pair of braces. I actually didn't even think this was valid syntax. What is this called and how does it work?

Comment: Here is the MDN definition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const testObject = {
    name: "myName",
    lastname: "lastName",
    address: "myAddress"
  }

  const {name, address} = testObject

  alert(name)
  alert(address)
```

The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from objects, into distinct variables.(Source: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

Which means in the assignment you are telling give me the value of the property `OperationHelper` from the module `require('apac')` and store it in a variable named `OperationHelper`. Check this small sample I have created